# NUnit, how do I execute source before and after running the test suite

Tags: .net, nunit, test-suite, suite

NUnit tests of different assemblies are collected and executed within a TestSuite. The TestSuites is a `*.nunit` project, created with NUnit GUI-runner.

For specific test purposes I need to execute a script before and also after the execution of all tests within that `.nunit` TestSuite.

How can I achieve this, by keeping the assurance that the script isn't executed somewhere in the middle of the TestSuite. **Execution order of test cases!**

---

***Structure:***

```
TestSuite_AllTests.nunit
    -> ### Run Script BEFORE ###
    -> Assembly1.Test
        -> TestClass1
            -> TestCase1
            -> TestCase2
        -> TestClass2
            -> TestCase1
            -> TestCase2
    -> Assembly2.Test
        -> TestClass1
            -> TestCase1
            -> TestCase2
    -> ### Run Script AFTER ###
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your [`Suite`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.5.6) and then add two methods with attributes to the class:

- `[TestFixtureSetUp]` for code executed before suite,
- `[TestFixtureTearDown]` for code executed after suite.

Example code:

```
public class AllTests
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("### Run Script BEFORE ###");
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("### Run Script AFTER ###");
    }

    [Suite]
    public static IEnumerable Suite
    {
        get
        {
            var suite = new ArrayList();
            suite.Add(new Assembly1.TestClass1());
            suite.Add(new Assembly1.TestClass2());
            suite.Add(new Assembly2.TestClass1());
            return suite;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, run NUnit GUI or NUnit Console using **/fixture:** command line option.

For example:

```
nunit-console /fixture:NUnit.Tests.AllTests nunit.tests.dll
```

Output for above code will be as following:

```
### Run Script BEFORE ###
***** Assembly1.TestClass1.Test1
***** Assembly1.TestClass1.Test2
***** Assembly1.TestClass2.Test1
***** Assembly1.TestClass2.Test2
***** Assembly2.TestClass1.Test1
### Run Script AFTER ###
```

However, you can't save such Suite as .nunit file.

As noted at NUnit [Suite](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.4.4) documentation:

> NUnit support for user-defined Suites currently has two
>   limitations:
>
> 1. It is not possible to include individual test cases directly in a Suite using the 
>      new approach. Anyone wanting to do so will need to use
>      the old approach and create an object derive from NUnit.Core.TestCase.
>      This is not recommended, since it requires a reference to the core
>      assembly.
> 2. Suites are currently not displayed in the Gui or run automatically by either runner when they are encountered. The historical purpose of
>      the Suite mechanism was to provide a way of aggregating tests at the
>      top level of each run. Hence, they are only supported when used with
>      the /fixture option on the console or gui command line.
>
> Approaches to removing these limitations are being investigated as
>   part of the planning for future NUnit releases.